# How can I make my <account> variable filterType equal to the first account returned in a StandardSetController Query?

Tags: picklist, pageblocktable, standardsetcontroller, querylocator

how would this work with a dynamic search page I have a visual force search page and I have used the stadardsetcontroller for pagination. The initial query during page load is working for me. Subsequent queries are not executed. How do we rerun the query in the controller. I thought we could just use the getAccounts() method after setting the controller object to null.

### Apex

```
public with sharing class Pagination {
    Public Integer noOfRecords{get; set;}
    Public Integer size{get;set;}
    public Account filterAccount{get;set;}


    public pagination()
    {
        filterAccount = new Account();

    }
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {
        get{
            if(setCon == null){
                size = 10;
                setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([Select Name, 
                    Type, Website, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingPostalCode, BillingCountry  
                    from Account Limit 1000]));
                setCon.setPageSize(size);
                noOfRecords = setCon.getResultSize();            
            }
            return setCon;
        }set;
    }


    Public List<Account> getAccounts(){
        List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
        for(Account a : (List<Account>)setCon.getRecords())
            accList.add(a); 

        return accList;
    }

    public pageReference refresh() {
        setCon = null;
        getAccounts();
        setCon.setPageNumber(1);
        return null;
    }

    public Boolean hasNext {
        get {
            return setCon.getHasNext();
        }
        set;
    }
    public Boolean hasPrevious {
        get {
            return setCon.getHasPrevious();
        }
        set;
    }

    public Integer pageNumber {
        get {
            return setCon.getPageNumber();
        }
        set;
    }

    public void first() {
        setCon.first();
    }

    public void last() {
        setCon.last();
    }

    public void previous() {
        setCon.previous();
    }

    public void next() {
        setCon.next();
    }
}
```

### VF:

```
<apex:page controller="Pagination" sidebar="false">
 <apex:form >



        <apex:outputPanel style="display: block" id="pwPanel">

          <apex:pageBlock >

               <apex:inputfield value="{!filterAccount.Type}" label="Account Type"> 
                 <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" action="{!refresh}" rerender="pwPanel"/>                  
               </apex:inputfield>

          <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!accounts.size>0}" id="list">

            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Accounts}" var="rl">
                            <apex:column headerValue="Account Name" value="{!rl.Name}">           
                            </apex:column>

                            <apex:column headerValue="Type">
                                <apex:outputField value="{!rl.Type}"/>
                            </apex:column>

                            <apex:column headerValue="Website">
                                <apex:outputField value="{!rl.Website}"/>
                            </apex:column>

                            <apex:column headerValue="Billing Street">
                                <apex:outputField value="{!rl.BillingStreet}"/>
                            </apex:column>

                            <apex:column headerValue="Billing City">
                                <apex:outputField value="{!rl.BillingCity}"/>
                            </apex:column>

                            <apex:column headerValue="Billing State">
                                <apex:outputField value="{!rl.BillingState}"/>
                            </apex:column>

                            <apex:column headerValue="Billing Zip/Postal Code">
                                <apex:outputField value="{!rl.BillingPostalCode}"/>
                            </apex:column>

                            <apex:column headerValue="Billing Country">
                                <apex:outputField value="{!rl.BillingCountry}" />
                            </apex:column>

            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            <apex:panelGrid columns="7">
                <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pb" value="|<" action="{!first}" disabled="{!!hasPrevious}" title="First Page"/>
                <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pb" value="<" action="{!previous}" disabled="{!!hasPrevious}" title="Previous Page"/>
                <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pb" value=">" action="{!next}" disabled="{!!hasNext}" title="Next Page"/>
                <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pb" value=">|" action="{!last}" disabled="{!!hasNext}" title="Last Page"/>
                <apex:outputText >{!(pageNumber * size)+1-size}-{!IF((pageNumber * size)>noOfRecords, noOfRecords,(pageNumber * size))} of {!noOfRecords}</apex:outputText>
                <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pb" value="Refresh" action="{!refresh}" title="Refresh Page"/>

                <apex:outputPanel style="color:#4AA02C;font-weight:bold">
                    <apex:actionStatus id="fetchStatus" startText="Fetching..." stopText=""/>
                </apex:outputPanel>

            </apex:panelGrid>
           </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlock>
      </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>


</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you clear the StandardSetController (`setCon = null`, line 36) and then access it again (`setCon.getRecords()`, line 29), the same initial query is executed again (line 16). This is not what you intended; you should initialize the standard controller, then initialize it again when you call `getAccounts()`. Also, your "reRender" attributes don't reference a valid element, so nothing is reRendered. Finally, your code can be heavily optimized. My optimizations are below.

## Notes

- `apex:column` is smart enough to use a field label when referencing a field.
- `setCon` methods can be called directly, avoiding the need to do so in Apex.
- `rerender` attribute must point to a valid ID, or nothing will be updated.

### Apex

```
public class pagination {
    public Account[] accounts { get { return setCon.getRecords(); } }
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon { get; set; }
    public Account filterAccount { get; set; }

    // Default constructor
    public pagination() {
        filterAccount = new Account();
        refresh();
    }
    public void refresh() {
        if(filterAccount.Type == null) {
            // No type selected
            setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController([
                SELECT Name, Type, Website, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingPostalCode, BillingCountry
                FROM Account
                LIMIT 10000
            ]);
        } else {
            // Find records with given type
            setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController([
                SELECT Name, Type, Website, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingPostalCode, BillingCountry
                FROM Account
                WHERE Type = :filterAccount.Type
                LIMIT 10000
            ]);
        }
        setCon.setPageSize(10);
    }

}
```

### Visualforce

```
<apex:page controller="pagination" sidebar="false">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:outputPanel style="display: block" id="pwPanel">
            <apex:pageBlock>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!filterAccount.Type}" label="Account Type">
                    <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" action="{!refresh}" rerender="pwPanel" />
                </apex:inputfield>
                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!setCon.pageSize>0}" id="list">
                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="rl">
                        <apex:column value="{!rl.Name}" />
                        <apex:column value="{!rl.Type}" />
                        <apex:column value="{!rl.Website}" />
                        <apex:column value="{!rl.BillingStreet}" />
                        <apex:column value="{!rl.BillingCity}" />
                        <apex:column value="{!rl.BillingState}" />
                        <apex:column value="{!rl.BillingPostalCode}" />
                        <apex:column value="{!rl.BillingCountry}" />
                    </apex:pageBlockTable>
                    <apex:panelGrid columns="7">
                        <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pwPanel" value="|<" action="{!setCon.first}"
                            disabled="{!!setCon.hasPrevious}" title="First Page" />
                        <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pwPanel" value="<"
                            action="{!setCon.previous}" disabled="{!!setCon.hasPrevious}" title="Previous Page" />
                        <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pwPanel" value=">" action="{!setCon.next}"
                            disabled="{!!setCon.hasNext}" title="Next Page" />
                        <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pwPanel" value=">|" action="{!setCon.last}"
                            disabled="{!!setCon.hasNext}" title="Last Page" />
                        <apex:outputText>
                            {!(setCon.pageNumber * setCon.pageSize)+1-setCon.pageSize}
                            -
                            {!MIN(setCon.pageNumber * setCon.pageSize, setCon.resultSize)} of {!setCon.resultSize}
                        </apex:outputText>
                        <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="pwPanel" value="Refresh" action="{!refresh}"
                            title="Refresh Page" />

                        <apex:outputPanel style="color:#4AA02C;font-weight:bold">
                            <apex:actionStatus id="fetchStatus" startText="Fetching..." stopText="" />
                        </apex:outputPanel>

                    </apex:panelGrid>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! The reason I used outputField is because inlineEdit does not work on columns:/